# How to rebase a single file in Git?

Tags: git

How do I rebase a single file so that all changes to it are in one commit?  I can't figure out any option to `git rebase` that would do the job.

Comment: You can use `git rebase -i` (interactive mode) and then squash all the commits you want into one commit. 
Running `git rebase -i` will give you the required help to squash the commits.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want correctly, you want to remove all the changes to a specified file from a range of commits in the repo's history (commits that may also include changes to other files) (a), and then re-add the changes to that specified file as one commit on top of the history (b).

Git really works on a whole-repository basis, not a per-file basis, so you will find no easy way in git to do this.

I think you'd need a combination of `git diff <begin> <end> -- <file>` to create the patch for (b) and then `git filter-branch` or the `bfg repo cleaner` to remove any changes to the file in question from a range of commits for (a).

Comment: Well, the reflog saves the pre-filter-branch state as well as the original refs do or how they are called. So no need to create a patch before, after the filter-branch or bfg you can simply check out the version of the file before the cleanup and commit it

Answer (score 0):

For illustration assume the file you want rebase is `target.c`. Further assume there are other files (bar.c and foo.c) that are also changed at the same time.

Finally, assume your git history resembles this (most recent on top).

```
 * END   - desired state of target.c
...
 * c2    - more changes to bar.c, foo.c, target.c
 * c1    - some changes to bar.c, foo.c, target.c
 * START - the commit you want to start your changes from
```

You can isolate the changes to `target.c` like this:

```
git checkout END
git reset --soft START
git add target.c
git commit -m "just changes to target.c"
```

at this point you will have a single commit from START with just the changes to target.c:

```
 * new   - just changes to target.c
 * START - the commit you want to start your changes from
```

The original commits (c1, c2, ... end) are still there and you can extract other files into other commits, etc.